# Css IE styling issue - How can I correct this simple navigation menu in IE?

Tags: css

I am working on a small website navigation issue and have the content working well in chrome, firefox and safari - but of course, IE fails to style the navigation menu at all.

I've created an unordered list and hacked styles onto it to make the menu horizontal.

Here is a direct link to the issue:  (link removed).

The unordered list appears as exactly that, a bulleted unordered vertical html list in IE rather than the nice looking navigation menu in chrome.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the `nav` issue (which prevents all styling in this case on older versions of IE), there appear to be other problems as well.

The HTML code uses `media` attributes that are not recognized by old versions of IE, which means that they apply none of the CSS files. The quick fix is to remove the `media` attribute from the `link` element that refers to Large.css. A better fix is to collect most of the CSS rules into a file that you refer to with a `link` element with `media=screen` (or no `media` attribute), so that the media width dependent CSS files contain only those settings that you want to be different for different widths.

The IE 9 console contains CSS3114 error messages that say that `@font-face` did not pass the usage rights checks for OpenType embedding.

Medium.css and Small.css contain `float: center` which is incorrect (`center` is not an accepted value for `float`). Use http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ to check your CSS code.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `<nav>` which is a HTML5 element. Old IE version (8 and lower) don't recognise them and don't style them.

To fix this you need to use [`HTML5shiv`](http://html5shiv.googlecode.com). Follow the instructions on that page to get it work.
In short, HTML5shiv creates every HTML element with `document.createElement` if you do that IE recognise them. To get the complete story: [Paul Irish: The history of the HTML5 shiv](http://paulirish.com/2011/the-history-of-the-html5-shiv/)

Comment: I added the code, but I see no effect on poor view of the nav on the IE 8 web browser - so the problem still exists...  Thanks so far though

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `nav` tags by `div` tags. It seems that no change to the CSS code is needed here, since you refer to the element using `#nav`, which works fine if you change `<nav id="nav">` to `<div id="nav">` (and `</nav>` to `</div>` of course).

Comment: why replacing a semantic good element (`<nav>`) with a no-semantic element (`<div>`) this is really not a good aproach.

Comment: There is no tangible evidence of actual benefits of using `nav`, and there is tangible evidence (like this) of its causing unnecessary trouble and decreased robustness (like relying on JavaScript on older browsers).

Comment: is there any SEO benefits to using nav?

Comment: Yes, and it is semantically much better. And HTML is designed to be semantic, not being easy to use for CSS. So it is much much much better to use the nav element. Some goods posts about this topic on HTML5doctor: [Let's Talk about Semantics](http://html5doctor.com/lets-talk-about-semantics/) and [Semantic navigation with the nav element](http://html5doctor.com/nav-element/)

Comment: No actual SEO benefits have ever been demonstrated.

Comment: The reason why the fix is not sufficient is that there are many other problems too.